# Specifying a different model than the controller name suggests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller

I've got a controller called "ResourcesController", but its really managing the CRUD for two different models.

I don't actually have a model called Resource, so the controller is balking that it can't find it.

Is there a way I can inform the controller which model I'll be working with so it doesn't freak out?

The error that is posted is this:

```
NameError in ResourcesController#new

uninitialized constant Resource
```

Here is the controller at the moment:

```
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController

 def new
 end

end
```

Comment: What is the actual error message? It would be also helpful if you could paste the content of the controller or part of it if it's large.

Comment: Is the controller generated from scaffold? What does your `config/routes.rb`

Comment: I guess you have another ResourcesController. Check the exact file and line in the error points to. Or you can do a "find in project"/"find in all files" for "Resource"

Comment: No the controller is not generated from a scaffold, and I don't think the error is that confusing.  Its telling me that I don't have a model called Resource, which is correct, I don't.  I want this ResourcesController to control two seperate model, Lessons and Exams.

Comment: A controller can work without any model at all. This controller would do nothing but try to render the views/resources/new.html.erb. You must have a reference somewhere to Resource, search for it, or follow the file/line numbers in the error backtrace.